# Extra row in Pivot Output

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I have a simple table that looks as follows:

[image]

I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DeviceId,
    [UCL],
    [LCL]
FROM dbo.BreweryTemperatureSetpoint
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SetpointValue) FOR SetpointName IN ([UCL], [LCL])
) AS PVT
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

What I would like is a single row that looks like this:

```
Prototype1, 24, 21.75
```

There is something about Pivot I don't quite understand since I would have thought my query would produce the desired output, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the fields in the "Source" to what is needed.   XAxis, YAxis and Value

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        Select DeviceId,SetpointValue,SetpointName
         FROM dbo.BreweryTemperatureSetpoint
     )  A
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SetpointValue) FOR SetpointName IN ([UCL], [LCL])
) AS PVT
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks very much.

Comment: @RandyMinder Happy to help.